# JSON deserialization on client side unable to parse the json string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

On click of an anchor tag the action of my controller is hit. there is a parameter that is passed in query string . I am converting a List to serialized json sting using the below code.

```
public ActionResult EmployeeVote(string regionID)
 {
   var nomineeList = NomineeModel.GetNomineeByRegionID(Convert.ToInt16(regionID));
   ViewBag.NomineeList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nomineeList,Formatting.None);
   return View(ViewBag);
 }
```

Ths json string I think there is some issue with the way the string is made.

```
[{&quot;Id&quot;:0,&quot;EmpId&quot;:1,&quot;FirstName&quot;:&quot;First Last&quot;,&quot;Email&quot;:&quot;mail@xyz.com&quot;,&quot;Description&quot;:null,&quot;RegionID&quot;:0}]
```

On client side.
But model list is giving error while deserializing it.

```
$(function () {
            var modelList = JSON.parse('@ViewBag.NomineeList');
           $(modelList).each((function () { //some logic});
 });
```

I want to perform an each loop to iterate over the model list to create some dynamic element. Any help ??

Comment: The string `[{&quot;Id&quot;:0,&quot;EmpId&quot;:1,&quot;FirstName&quot;:&quot;First Last&quot;,&quot;Email&quot;:&quot;mail@xyz.com&quot;,&quot;Description&quot;:null,&quot;RegionID&quot;:0}]` [is not valid JSON.](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: @MattBall I thought so can you point why the string is wrongly made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `@ViewBag.NomineeList` will HTML-encode the json string. You need to prevent this, but still make sure the string is a valid javascript string.

In the controller:

```
ViewBag.NomineeList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nomineeList, Formatting.None)
    );
```

The `JavaScriptSerializer` makes sure that the string is save to be used in JS, so new lines are encoded etc.

Then, in the view:

```
var modelList = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.NomineeList));
```

- Use `Html.Raw` to prevent HTML encoding
- Don't enclose this in quotes as this is already done by `JavaScriptSerializer`

---

Update: I added an example how you could make it work without using `JavaScriptSerializer`. But I reconsidered the potential dangers and I've removed it. Stick to the approach above using `JavaScriptSerializer`, it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ad hock solution: 
Replace the """

```
ViewBag.NomineeList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nomineeList,Formatting.None).Remove(" &quot;");
```

Also try using http://json.codeplex.com/.